# In IONIC 3, How do I upload a file such as a word or pdf on ios ?

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova-plugins, ionic3, ionic-native

I am not sure where to start, I have used the phonegap filechooser, but not sure how to read the file and send its contents afterwords to the server

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use [**File Transfer**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/) and [**File**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/) native plugins for your task.

*Extracted from the official doc:*

> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
>
> npm install --save @ionic-native/file-transfer
>
> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
>
> npm install --save @ionic-native/file

*.ts*

```
import { FileTransfer, FileUploadOptions, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';

constructor(private transfer: FileTransfer, private file: File) { }


const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

// Upload a file:
fileTransfer.upload(..).then(..).catch(..);

// Download a file:
fileTransfer.download(..).then(..).catch(..);

// Abort active transfer:
fileTransfer.abort();

// full example
upload() {
  let options: FileUploadOptions = {
     fileKey: 'file',
     fileName: 'name.jpg',
     headers: {}
   }

  fileTransfer.upload('<file path>', '<api endpoint>', options)
   .then((data) => {
     // success
   }, (err) => {
     // error
   })
}

download() {
  const url = 'http://www.example.com/file.pdf';
  fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + 'file.pdf').then((entry) => {
    console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
  }, (error) => {
    // handle error
  });
}
```

Comment: That is to transfer the file itself, but how do i get the file. The fileChooser is only supported in Android. And the phoneGap FilePicker returns a uri which I can't seem to use to read into the file content.

Comment: You can use `download()` method as shown in my post above.